# Ramda, check if string is valid

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

Valid value:

- Is string or number (R.is(string), R.is(number)
- Is not equal to '-' and '$' and '0'
- Is not null, false, undefined or NaN (Number.isNaN)

How do I make a `const isValid = ...` function of this with ramda?

The `where` function is close https://ramdajs.com/docs/#where. But it only accepts and object where you can check each prop.

The `both` function only accepts two arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use `both` if you separate the type check and the content check:

```js
const isValid = both(
  either(is(String), is(Number)),
  complement(anyPass([
    isNil, 
    equals('0'),
    equals('-'),
    equals('$'),
    equals(NaN),
    equals(false)
  ]))
);

console.log(isValid([]));
console.log(isValid(1));
console.log(isValid(NaN));
console.log(isValid('foo'));
console.log(isValid('$'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {both, either, is, complement, anyPass, isNil, equals} = R;</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that some of your rules are redundant.  Since it has to be a string or a number it already cannot be `null`, `false`, or `undefined`.  So your logic can be simpler.

I would suggest using Ramda for several helper functions here, but perhaps not using a pure point-free Ramda function.  This seems to capture it just fine:

```js
const isValid = s => 
  (is (String, s) || is (Number, s)) && ! includes (s, [NaN, '-', '$', '0'] );

['a', 'b', 42, false, NaN, null, '-', '-0', '$', {}].forEach(s =>
  console.log(`${s} => ${isValid(s)}`)   
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script><script>
const {is, includes} = R                                                      </script>
```

A plain JS version of the same code would look like:

```js
const isValid = s => 
  (typeof s == 'string' || typeof s == 'number') && ! [NaN, '-', '$', '0'] .includes (s);
```

The Ramda version is slightly simpler and to my eyes, a bit more readable.  I would never include Ramda just for that little difference.  But if already using Ramda, then this version makes sense.

But a completely point-free Ramda version looks *less* simple to me.  It's not horrible, but I wouldn't choose it, even if it's fairly easy to write:

```js
const isValid = both (
  either ( is (String), is (Number) ), 
  complement (includes (__, [NaN, '-', '$', '0'] ) )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This task is better solved in plain JavaScript:

```
function isValid(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'string' && typeof value !== 'number')
        return false;

    if (value === '-' || value === '$' || value === '0')
         return false;

    if (value === null || value === false || value === undefined || Number.isNaN(value))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

This is easy to understand, reasonably short code. I don't see how using Ramda could improve this.

Answer (score 0):

This uses Ramda in as many ways as I can think:

```
const isValid = arg => R.both(R.is(String, arg) || R.is(Number, arg), R.both(R.not(R.includes(arg, ["$", "-", "0"])), R.not(arg)));
```